# Singleton design pattern to get a RoomDatabase instance

Tags: android, singleton, android-room

I´m working with RoomDatabase and after setting up my DAO, Database, and Entity classes I need to find a way to get the RoomDatabase instance, but on the documentation, I see this:

> If your app runs in a single process, you should follow the singleton
> design pattern when instantiating an AppDatabase object. Each
> RoomDatabase instance is fairly expensive, and you rarely need access
> to multiple instances within a single process.

So from the [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/new-android-fundamentals--ud851) courses I see there are various ways to do this the first one:

```
private lateinit var INSTANCE: MainDBForObjects
fun getDatabase(context: Context): MainDBForObjects{
    if (!::INSTANCE.isInitialized){
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
            context,
            MainDBForObjects::class.java, "database"
        ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }
    return INSTANCE
}
```

and the other one is with a companion object from the database abstract class:

```
 companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: SleepDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): SleepDatabase {

            synchronized(this) {

                var instance = INSTANCE

                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context.applicationContext,
                            SleepDatabase::class.java,
                            "sleep_history_database"
                    )
         
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build()
             
                    INSTANCE = instance
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
```

So is there any important difference between these 2? is it one better than the other?

Comment: first approach is not thread-safe, the second one is also an incorrect implementation of double check locking so though it's thread-safe has a higher incurred cost of synchronization (acquiring locks) even if the instance is already initialized

Comment: could you please add this as the answer along with the correct implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Added an implementation to create a Singleton object through double check locking.

This would ensure that a lock is only acquired when required (if the database object is uninitialized) as synchronization is generally expensive

The double check here refers to the null check again within `synchronized` block, this helps us in scenarios where a `thread A` had acquired the lock to initialize the object for the first time and other threads were also waiting for it `(thread B, C)` now as soon as `thread A` initializes the object and releases the lock all waiting threads immediately get the updated value.

The need for using a local variable is to ensure that partially initialized objects are not visible to threads leading to inconsistent state (related to language semantics, more info here --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java)

```
companion object {

    @Volatile
    private var sInstance: SleepDatabase? = null

    @JvmStatic
    fun getInstance(context: Context): SleepDatabase {
        val localInstance = sInstance

        if (localInstance != null) {
            return localInstance
        }

        return synchronized(this) {
            var instance = sInstance
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                                 context.applicationContext,
                                 SleepDatabase::class.java,
                                 "sleep_history_database"
                               )
                               .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                               .build()
                 sInstance = instance
            }

            instance
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I´m getting this error "Smart cast to 'MainDBForObjects' is impossible, because 'sInstance' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time"

Comment: Yup that's a lint check which we can solve by introducing a local variable. In our  example we can be sure the `sInstance` is not changed outside our method `getInstance` but static analysis is unable to comprehend it and complains because it sees a mutable property that could be null